# load html text of https (SSL)

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know how to load the HTML element of https in asp.net?

say.. you have the following url: https://somesite.com/secure/site.aspx. How do I programatically load the html content of the this url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
string source;
using(var client = new WebClient())
    source = client.DownloadString(url);
```